# Placing breakpoints in DLL's Visual Studio instance and breaking in .exe's*

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, dll

**Situation:**

I'm developing a set of DLL libraries and am separately using them in a project where I test them. I often need to break at a faulty point, but while usually I anyway get an exception and VS finds the source file for me and the right spot, allowing me to break there, there are occasions when there's no error but unwanted results, so I need to peek inside and look at the actual data I could of course start navigating through to that point from debug mode in the .exe's solution, but it's buried a few function calls deep and I'll probably end up with 5-6 more files open than I need, plus the time of finding it.
**Question:**

Is there any way to make one instance of VS break at a specific point via a breakpoint in another instance? Given that they both see the same .pdb file for debugging info within the DLL, I would imagine they could also share such info, but apparently not(?). I do recall seeing a question about skipping breakpoints in DLLs so I imagine there *is* something doable.

*current alternative:*

So far I'm limited to purposefully inject faulty bits of code to make the second instance open the file at the right point, usually a division by zero does the trick, but it's still a little back-and-forth. Note that it's VS2010 right now, though I imagine they haven't changes something concerning this in the subsequent versions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  BTW, you're better off using [DebugBreak](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679297(v=vs.85).aspx) then divide by zero.

Comment: I want to make the .exe's debugger to see the breakpoints from the other (the DLL's) solution, that's all.

Comment: Why not put everything in one solution?  (That's why they call it a "solution".)

Comment: Well, I was hoping I'd keep the DLLs as separated as possible so I don't unconsciously modify the generic DLLs to fit the specific project. Actually, this is the only reason I have seen so far for putting everything in one solution actually. So I admit it's a matter of preference and comfort :)

Comment: This is called a self-inflicted injury.

Comment: Programming is a masochistic discipline, and programmers an arrogant species, after all we wouldn't have so many languages etc if we didn't always try to work with what we're comfortable with, right? Also, I submit that the point of problem solving is finding a solution that fits the problem without altering the parameters, if that doesn't exist then we can try to revise the problem

Comment: Breakpoints belong to a Solution, not to a .pdb (symbol) file, and are set by an attached debugger.  Only one debugger can be attached to a process.  When you add breakpoints in Visual Studio, they are not persisted to disk unless you save the solution (or explicitly export the breakpoints).

Comment: That's actually a good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
Debugger.Break();
```

it signals a breakpoint to an attached debugger. Just put it in a library you want to debug, start your program and it will stop on this line.

Comment: You can always include the assembly to System.Debugging ;) By the way @Damian, I rarely get an answer around here that does not try to alter the problem to fit it, I salute you!

Comment: Please add a language tag to the post.  Note that System.Debugging and Debugger.Break don't apply to C.

Comment: This does not concern a language in my opinion, you can make a call to Debugger.break() from any object oriented language, C#, VB, C++ etc, as it resides in a DLL file itself and is thus accessible externally in a language-agnostic fashion. I would however suggest that @Damian adds the detail that it is in the System.Diagnostics Assembly so everyone else can find it, for a bulletproof answer.

Comment: Debugger.Break is part of the .NET framework.  For unmanaged code, you would use DebugBreak.